# Cant download a SWF image or preview it using PHP

Tags: php, flash

Hi Stack**overflow** community,

I've been trying to download a swf image from a extern server, which you can reach by a simple url.

Sadly the downloaded SWF wouldn't show up in the browser, so i assume its a broken file. Also I'm not able to preview the SWF file through PHP.

I know I could embed the SWF but i kinda need a screenshot or a downloaded version of it.

Code I've tested to download the SWF to my server:

```
function save_swf(){
    $swf_file = file_get_contents('http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/avatar/avatar10.8.swf?u=' . $this->username);
    file_put_contents(strtolower($this->award . '_' . $this->username . '.swf'), $this->swf);
}
```

Code which i used to check if the image can be previewn by PHP:

```
<?php
        $data = @file_get_contents('http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/avatar/avatar10.swf?u=dane');
        header("content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline;" echo $data);
        header("accept-ranges: bytes", true);
        header("connection: keep-alive", true);
        echo $data;
    ?>
```

Does anyone have a idea why it wouldn't work?

Basis SWF im trying to get the file from: http://assets.zwinky.com/assets3/avatar/avatar10.8.swf?u=dane

Comment: `?u=dane` part of the url is a `$_GET` string, which means the actual `swf` file doesn't contain the data needed to display the avatar it is instead making another call to the server to download that information and then display it.  Chances are the server in question does not allow outside domains to make this call and the data will not be loaded.

Comment: This actually seems logical. I guess it is pulling the other informations through a xml which stores the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the data to a file locally on the server, the following should work:

```
// Write swf file locally using file_put_contents();
$fileName = ""; // The filepath where you've written it to

header("Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash",true);    
header("Content-Length: {strlen($fileName)}",true);    
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes",true);    
header("Connection: keep-alive",true);   
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$fileName");  

readfile($fileName);
```

Let me know if you need any addition help with this.

Comment: The only problem, with this is: I can't really download a working version of the SWF to my server using the code i posted up there. It would download but once i drag it into my browser, it will show empty.